# Using a shell script with jstest, how can I get a gamepad to interact with my script?

Tags: shell-script

I have been partially successful with this, but I am stuck. Here is my script:

I want to prompt the user, wait for input from a USB gamepad, and then execute a command based on which button is pressed.

```
if lsusb | grep -q '0583:2060'
then
  echo "press the A button"
  #
  if jstest --event /dev/input/js0 | grep -q "number 0, value 1"
  then
    echo "you pressed the A button"
  else
    echo "you pressed the NOT A button"
  fi
fi
```

It checks for the gamepad being connected just fine. It also checks the jstest and echos "you pressed the A button" when I press the A button.

I can't get it to execute the "else" part in this situation though, as grep filters only "button 0, value 1" from jstest (the A button), which means if I am not pressing the A button jstest is piping NOTHING to grep, it always waits for the A button.

I was thinking maybe there was some way to do:

```
grep -q "number ., value 1"
```

which will return ANY button being pressed, and then have different commands executed based on what what grep shows. I thought I could use a case statement for this, but I can't get jstest to work with case.

I feel like jstest isn't meant for this kind of stuff, only to test, but extensive googling has shown me no other options for interacting with a game pad through a script.

How can I make a shell script that prompts the user, waits for a button press, then executes different commands based on which button was pressed?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's going on; if you press a button *other than* "A", what does the `jstest` command output?

Comment: Jstest starts a "test" program showing the status of all controller buttons, at once. The "--event" part of the command instead makes it shows one line for every event, key press and release. Grepping it with "number 0, value 1" literally makes it _only_ output something when button 0's value is 1 (pressing the A button). If I press/release B, X, R, etc, jstest doesn't do anything. It is still sitting, waiting, normally blocking the terminal until it shows "number 0, value 1".

Answer (score 1):

You need to get `grep` to output the matching text, *and* stop after a match. You also need to filter events a bit more thoroughly, since you’re only interested in events of type 1 (buttons):

```
jstest --event /dev/input/js0 | grep -m 1 "type 1, time .*, number .*, value 1"
```

This will keep `jstest` running until you press a button, then output the event information. You can process this using `read` to find the number of the button that was pressed:

```
jstest --event /dev/input/js0 | grep -m 1 "type 1, time .*, number .*, value 1" | read _ _ _ _ _ _ number _ _
if [ "${number%%,*}" -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "You pressed the A button."
else
    echo "You pressed a button other than A."
fi
```